# Count packets actively in Ns2

Tags: queue, tcl, ns2, otcl

I have to count packets for each incoming flow actively in **RED Queue** in **Ns2**. I have to integrate it in the queue algorithm itself so that changes (in variables of active queues) occur when the packet in queued. For simple codes it's like:

```
 for each incoming packet
     count[i]=count[i]+packet[i]
```

How do I say “for each incoming packet” in NS2, and how do I define `[i]` such that `[i]` is the IP Address representing different individual flow?

Comment: I guess you should look for a callback to let you respond to an incoming/received packet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by modifying the .cc and .h files of the queue implementation which can be found  at

ns-allinone-x.xx\ns-x.xx\queue.

See the following link for more information

http://www.projectguideline.com/topic/can-we-view-the-packet-content-in-ns2-not-the-header/

Comment: Please take a look at [Limits for self-promotion in answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/349071).  I would suggest removing your name and homepage from your answer, lest it be marked as spam.